# client-server programming through a proxy

Tags: c++, sockets, proxy

In my client-server case, the client sends a file to the server through a proxy sever. I frequently used FTP client-server but don't know how to pass through a proxy.

**client <-> proxy server <-> server**

Here is the code for client:

```
    SOCKET Connect;
Connect= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);


SOCKADDR_IN addrss;
int addrss_length = sizeof(addrss);
addrss.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
addrss.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrss.sin_port = htons(6783);

connect(Connect, (SOCKADDR*) &addrss, sizeof(addrss));...
```

Here is the code for server:

```
SOCKADDR_IN addrss;
int addrss_length = sizeof(addrss);
addrss.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
addrss.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrss.sin_port = htons(6783);


SOCKET Listen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
SOCKET Connect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,NULL);


bind(Listen, (SOCKADDR*) &addrss, addrss_length);

listen(Listen,5);
```

Comment: What is the question? What kind of proxy is it? What kind of protocol (HTTP, FTP, ...)?

Comment: Normally the use of the proxy is pretty transparent, just write normal socket code.  The proxy might use different port numbers, so you have to check that.